# Import model from another app Django

Tags: django

I have a problem importing a model from another app. I am using `Django 2.0`.

My project structure looks like this:

```
--api
  --api
    --settings.py
    --urls.py
    --wsgi.py
  --product
    --models.py
  --chat
    --models.py
--manage.py
```

To show only the problem I have I simplified the structure. If you are missing something important let me know it.

The file causing the error:

**chat/models.py**

```
from api.product.models import Product
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db import models


class Chat(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product)
    enquirer = models.ForeignKey(User)
```

**product/models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Product(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, related_name='category', on_delete=None)
    front_image = models.ImageField(upload_to="")
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    price = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    description = models.CharField(max_length=5000)
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

**settings.py**

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'account.apps.AccountConfig',
    'product.apps.ProductConfig',
    'profileInfo.apps.ProfileInfoConfig',
    'chat.apps.ChatConfig',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'rest_framework',
    'rest_framework.authtoken',
    'corsheaders',
]
```

The error is the following: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'api.product'` I do not understand why Django even can not find `api.product`.

Is that a common problem ? Thank you for your help.

Comment: You should import it as `from product.models import Product`.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Based on your settings and the file directory, the project root is the uppest `app` directory. So that means that you import the models by writing:

```
from product.models import Product
```

instead of:

```
from api.product.models import Product
```

If your IDE suggested that import, something is probably wrong with the *project root*.

Comment: Don't trust an IDE. Think yourself. That is what I learned today..  Thank you.

Comment: @Coder949: perhaps you have set the project root wrong in your IDE. I suggest to take a look at this, since otherwise it will be rather inconvenient to do development.

Comment: Fixed it. I think PyCharm sets the root dynamically. I openend the project one folder too early.

Answer (score 12):

The solution I found that works for me using Python 3.x

`...`
`from django.apps import apps`
`...`

and then whereever in your code you need to import a model you can do the following.
`...`
`model = apps.get_model('app_name', 'ModelName')`
`...`

Comment: thanks, @Yunnosch for pointing out that I didn't give a solution. I hope I did it right this time.

Comment: thanks again @Yunnosch, I removed my own question from my answer but my solution is addressing the problem that Coder949 described in the question.