# i want to import all classes from a model.py which is not in my app modules in Django

Tags: python, django, module, model

in Django, my model.py is out of my App modules I want to import all the classes from that model.py to all modules. I searched a lot I didn't get anything can anyone help me

here is my directory

```
C:
│   manage.py
│   **models.py**
│   mysqlclient-1.4.6-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl
│
│
├───myshop
│   │   asgi.py
│   │   settings.py
│   │   urls.py
│   │   wsgi.py
│   │   __init__.py
│   │
├───products
│   │   admin.py
│   │   apps.py
│   │   tests.py
│   │   views.py
│   │   __init__.py
│   │
│   ├───migrations
│   │   │   __init__.py
```

Comment: What is the models.py file path (folder location)  ??

Comment: please provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I think you're question is answered here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50670173/import-model-from-another-app-django